# How to analyze Circular Dichroism data? Best practices, typical approaches and so on

Tags: structural-biology

I have to analyze circular dichroism data of proteins and nucleic acids for my PhD. Despite I have been able to find vast literature that helps to interpret a spectrum, most of the papers describe only the experiment as is, so telling what the methods to acquire a good set of spectra were, using JASCO technology or Synchrotron Radiation Circular Dichroism (SRCD), and the final interpretation of the plot.

Basically, I come from biomedical signal analysis and processing. So I was thinking that extracting features from spectra could be kind of similar to extracting features from an ECG signal for example.

Given that I don't precisely know what the experts do with cd spectra, If you have any advice could be of great value to me.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear about the question or the project. Are ECG's electro-cardiograms? Interpreting ECG's you'd have thought would be applicable to spectral analysis (its obvious). However, I believe a cardiologist is better positioned to identify aberrations and ECG spectral analysis is certainly not mainstream if done at all (I think the latter is correct).

Comment: https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2021/cs/d0cs00558d --> Tools and methods for circular dichroism spectroscopy of proteins: a tutorial review

Comment: take two different protein that fold in the most similar ways and get their structure then calculate both CD spetra ? calculate all the predicted CD spectra of all the alfa-fold predicted structure and figure out if you can given a CD spectra get the name of the protein ?? play with the data using AI to figure out pattern (i.e. percentage of alpha elical vs betha sheets and so on ...